# How to extract Android backup TAR file correctly?

Tags: java, android, tar, android-backup-service

I have taken backup of user's data by using Helium application. I have got an .ab file and using backup extractor in Windows, I have converted the .ab file into .tar file using this command:

```
java -jar abe.jar unpack filename.ab filename.tar
```

But I can't extract that .tar file using winrar, it always says:

```
Warning, no archive found!
```

and `The archive is either in unknown format or damaged`

I have installed tar in my Windows machine and ran this code

```
$ tar -xvf filename.tar
```

but no luck, is there anything I am missing? I need the app data as it's a running application so I can't run it in Android Studio because it says all of my data will be wiped off.

Comment: What sort of format does Helium write? - is a `.ab` an encoded tar file? I wonder if it has a verbose mode so you can see details of the data as it writes it? Are there any docs on this? When you say "no luck" in relation to using `tar`, what happened? What error did you get?